# Matar processo externo quando fechar form

Tags: c#, vb.net

Eu criei um formulário que executa um programa externo quando clico em um botão carregar programa, porem quando eu fecho o formulário eu queria que ele ele desse um kill process no gerenciador de tarefas.

Porém ele fala que tem acesso negado quando fecho o formulário, parece que ele até tenta matar processo mais não funciona.

Dentro do `Form1_FormClosing` ficou assim:

```
Process[] myProcesses;
myProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("meu programa");
foreach (Process myProcess in myProcesses)
{
    if (myProcess.CloseMainWindow())
        myProcess.Close();

    if (!myProcess.HasExited)
        myProcess.Kill();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá,
Por gentileza... Tente armazenar o processo do programa externo em uma variável no momento em que ele é iniciado, para que você tenha certeza que no momento de fechar o formulário você esteja fechando o programa que você iniciou.

No exemplo abaixo, no método buttonLoadProgram_MouseUp o programa externo é iniciado utilizando System.Diagnostics.Process e este processo é armazenado na variável global MyProcess. No método Form1_FormClosing o processo armazenado na variável global MyProcess é finalizado dentro de um Try...catch onde você poderá analisar melhor o erro que você esta tentando superar.

Segue o código completo, e em seguida conte-nos o que ocorreu :)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {

    /// <summary>
    /// Variavel para guardar o processo.
    /// </summary>
    public Process MyProcess;

    /// <summary>
    /// Contrutor
    /// </summary>
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inicia o programa externo
    /// </summary>
    private void buttonLoadProgram_MouseUp
        (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        MyProcess = new Process();
        //Caminho do programa
        MyProcess.StartInfo.
            FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe";

        MyProcess.Start();
        MyProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ao fechar o form o programa externo tb é fechado.
    /// </summary>
    private void Form1_FormClosing
        (object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Finalizando programa
            MyProcess.Kill();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //Observe o erro e tente nos contar mais sobre o ocorrido
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Adriano Silva Ribeiro, Obrigado pela sua ajuda, mas su codigo já esta identico ao meu, o erro quando fecho o form e ele tenta fechar or programa é a seguinte msg:

Comment: O acesso ao caminho 'C:\Windows\System32\SistemaB.exe' foi negado